pyTelegrambotAPI - не могу разобраться
Имеется кнопка подтверждения номера:
keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=True)
    contact_button = types.KeyboardButton("Подтвердить номер телефона", request_contact=True)
    keyboard.add(contact_button)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, WELCOME_MESSAGE, reply_markup=keyboard)

Имеется декоратор на получения контакта, но есть проблема, он считывает не нажатие на кнопку "ок", а получения контакта, соответственно, бота можно обмануть просто прикрепив контакт любого человека не нажимая при этом на кнопку подтверждения номера, как это исправить?
Разумеется номера телефона я не знаю и знать не могу.
Неужели у Глаза Бога есть точно такой же баг?
 @bot.message_handler(content_types=['contact'])
def handle_contact(message):
    pass


